# Microsoft 365 Graph API - how to read mail box of all users

Tags: python, api, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a Microsoft 365 admin user.
I try to read other users’ emails using the Microsoft 365 graph API.

I adopted the following from [github](https://github.com/jasonjoh/python_tutorial) based on a [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python):

```
import requests

graph_endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0{0}'


def make_api_get_call(url, token, parameters=None):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f'Bearer {token}',
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
    return requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=parameters, timeout=10)


def get_messages(access_token, user, results_to_return="10"):
    get_messages_url = graph_endpoint.format(
        f'/users/{user}/mailfolders/inbox/messages')

    query_parameters = {
        "$top": results_to_return,
        "$select": "receivedDateTime,subject,from,body",
        "$orderby": "receivedDateTime DESC",
    }

    return make_api_get_call(get_messages_url, access_token, parameters=query_parameters)
```

I am able to read my own emails, but for some reason, when I try to set the variable user to another email account - I get the following error:

> 404: {"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified
> object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the
> correct
> properties.","innerError":{"date":"2021-09-13T04:33:48","request-id":"42bba137-a852-43e2-97e7-387a95892223","client-request-id":"42bba137-a852-43e2-97e7-387a95892223"}}}

What do I need to do to make it work?
Thanks.

[image]/rareB.png

Comment: Definitely tangential to the question’s core here, but *why* do you want to do this…? Isn’t this a particularly egregious invasion of privacy to be reading emails arbitrarily without at least just cause to do so (even if you are ultimately providing email say for employees)?

Comment: Great point, thanks. I'll never read private emails. The email content will never be exposed to the human eye. I build a tool that will automate manual labor (like Calendly and Grammarly), and so I need the tool to have this access.

Comment: Using [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)? Which Api did you use in your code? Could you pls share the api document link? And according to the 404 error code, is it possible that user doesn't have an email account or doesn't have a folder named inbox?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Microsoft 365 admin user. I try to read other users’ emails using the Microsoft 365 graph API.

Admin users don't have the permission to read other people mailboxes eg if you tried to do this in OWA or Outlook you would get the same issue. You need explicitly delegate access to a Mailbox using something like Add-MailboxPermission https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/add-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Is there an automatic way to do so using 365 API ? (I use the cloud)

Comment: If you want access to every mailbox in the tenant then use Application permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: I am using application permission - I added a screenshot. This sill doesn't work.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error message ? its strange because that error you posted is the same error you get when don't have permission when using delegation. You could check the token with https://jwt.io/